# trying to fetch the last message in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

This is my query:

```
SELECT u.ProfilePic AS FriendPic, u.UserName AS FriendName, m.*
FROM (SELECT PhotographerId
      FROM Messages
      WHERE UserId=? OR PhotographerId=?
      GROUP BY PhotographerId
     ) AS m JOIN
     User AS u
     ON u.UserId = m.PhotographerId;
```

I'm trying to make SQL query from table, - get last messages from all pairs of users with user ? as sender or recipient, and join them with users table to get names. I've managed to create something like this, but still want to ask if there is more simple

i want to fetch the photogrpher name, profile pic and last message of every user as we see in inbox..

table
user: profile pic, username,user_id

message: userid, photographerid, message, timestamp

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I don't think this query does what you want.

Comment: Plus we really need to see the query as it would look when parsed by your application code. '?' doesn't mean much in isolation.

Comment: Add complete structure of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.userid AS 'User id', u1.profile_pic AS 'User pic', u1.username AS 'User name`,
m.photographerid AS 'Photographer id', u2.profile_pic AS 'Photographer pic', 
u2.username AS 'Photographer name`,
m.message, m.timestamp
FROM message m JOIN user u1 ON m.userid = u1.user_id
JOIN user u2 ON m.photographerid = u2.user_id
ORDER BY m.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**Update**:

You can get latest messages for a user with the below query:

```
SELECT m.userid, a.photographerid, m.message, a.timestamp
FROM message m
JOIN (SELECT photographerid, MAX(timestamp) as timestamp
FROM message where userid = ?
GROUP BY photographerid
) a
ON m.photographerid = a.photographerid and m.timestamp = a.timestamp
WHERE m.userid = ?

UNION

SELECT a.userid, m.photographerid, m.message, a.timestamp
FROM message m
JOIN (SELECT userid, MAX(timestamp) as timestamp
FROM message where photographerid = ?
GROUP BY userid
) a
ON m.userid = a.userid and m.timestamp = a.timestamp
WHERE m.photographerid = ?
```

Once you get the message, you can JOIN the output of this query with user table to get the values of other columns, e.g.:

```
SELECT m.userid AS 'User id', u1.profile_pic AS 'User pic', u1.username AS 'User name`,
m.photographerid AS 'Photographer id', u2.profile_pic AS 'Photographer pic', 
u2.username AS 'Photographer name`,
m.message, m.timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT m.userid, a.photographerid, m.message, a.timestamp
    FROM message m
    JOIN (SELECT photographerid, MAX(timestamp) as timestamp
    FROM message where userid = ?
    GROUP BY photographerid
    ) a
    ON m.photographerid = a.photographerid and m.timestamp = a.timestamp
    WHERE m.userid = ?

    UNION

    SELECT a.userid, m.photographerid, m.message, a.timestamp
    FROM message m
    JOIN (SELECT userid, MAX(timestamp) as timestamp
    FROM message where photographerid = ?
    GROUP BY userid
    ) a
    ON m.userid = a.userid and m.timestamp = a.timestamp
    WHERE m.photographerid = ?
) m JOIN user u1 ON m.userid = u1.user_id
JOIN user u2 ON m.photographerid = u2.user_id;
```

Comment: how you will get last message, your query will give all message.

Comment: @AshutoshSIngh it's not entirely clear from question how OP needs to order the messages. However, I have updated the answer and added a note in it.

Comment: Completely hypothetical answer, at least it's clear that OP wants to fetch user's latest message with their details.

Comment: @Suraz `get last messages from all pairs of users` don't know where it says latest message.

Comment: i want only last message.
see i have 2 tables aand i want profile pic and username from user table and
last message and time from message table

Comment: Accepted, you can consider that in your answer.

Comment: @Shifali I have amended the answer, it _should_ only return latest message now.

Comment: see as in inbox we have done chat with say 10 person then that 10 person's last message should be shown.

Comment: This will ignore null results (obviously)

Comment: @Shifali so you want the last message for each and every person the said user had a chat with?

Comment: i am unable to fetch profilepic and username from user table @DarshanMehta? although the query is right

Comment: @Shifali added another query in the answer.

Comment: i am getting double data i.e 1--9
                                            1--26
                                             26--1
                                             9--1
i want single data..